# Adding data to DataSet that has existing data

Tags: c#, datagridview

I've added a new column to an existing dataset that has data in it, and displayed it in a DGV, this is what I've done :

```
string con = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=""C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Login\Login\Student_Marks.mdf"";Integrated Security=True";
            string sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_ExamMarks";
            go.setConn(con, sql);
            DataSet ds = go.getDatabaseData;
            ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("Final_Mark", typeof(double));            
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Now I'm try to fill the new column rows with data,this is what I've done:

```
double dp;
            double exam;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {

                double.TryParse(row.Cells[5].Value.ToString(), out dp);
                double.TryParse(row.Cells[6].Value.ToString(), out exam);
                row.Cells[7].Value = (dp * (40 / 100)) + (exam * (60 / 100));
            }
```

when I run this, I get an error that says

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
in this statement `double.TryParse(dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value.ToString(), out dp);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another way, set the [Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) property when you build your new column

So, supposing that your two columns at index 5 and index 7 are named `dp` and `exam` then you could write this when you add the new column

```
ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("Final_Mark", 
                         typeof(double), 
         "([dp] * (40 / 100)) + ([exam] * (60 / 100))");
```

Of course this remove the need to execute your own loop to initialize the column `Final_Mark`

Comment: to be clear, so after the above statement there is no need for the `foreach()` loop?

Comment: thanks a lot, but why my above code is giving me an error I don't understand

Comment: Do you see any row where the new column contains NULL instead of the result of your expression? If yes then those rows contain a null value in the column dp or exam. This is automatically handled by the expression while in code writing _Value.ToString()_ raises the error. And yes, you could remove the foreach loop